# groovy - xml - preserve attribute order

Tags: xml, groovy

I need to print XML that I manipulated using groovy and maintain the attribute order.  I don't care if it's using XmlParser/XmlNodePrinter or XmlSlurper/StreamingMarkupBuilder.  My current code is as follows:

```
File file = new File('input.xml')
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

def admins = root.user.findAll {it.@role.text().equals("admin")}
admins.each { admin ->
  admin.permission.findAll { it.@interface.text().equals("RoleManagement") 
  }.each {
    it.@implementation = "AdminRoleManagement"
  }
}

def smb = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield root }
new File('output.xml').text = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(smb)
```

Here's the XML that gets fed into the program

```
<users>
  <user username="test1234" role="admin">
    <permission interface="com.test.RoleManagement" implementation="com.test.AdminRoleManagement"/>
    <permission interface="com.test.UserAdministration" implementation="com.test.UserAdministrationImpl"/>
  </user>
</users>
```

After I print out the modified file, though, the interface and implementation attributes are reversed.

I already know what you're thinking: xml attribute order does not matter.  Well, my requirement from my boss is to preserve the attribute order b/c it has been that way for ages.  I was actually supposed to write this parser using Java/DOM4J and I was trying to show my team something new.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some example xml you could paste into the question that exhibits the problem?

Comment: added some sample xml - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without writing your own code to output the XML.

The SAX parser has no concept of attribute ordering (AFAIK), and so the order will be lost before `XmlSlurper` even sees the data...  I found a [thread on the groovy-user list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/XmlSlurper-order-of-attributes-td354329.html) which has a discussion of this, but it doesn't seem to come up with any solutions...

I *think* it's possible with `XmlParser`, as that seems to maintain order:

```
def xml = '''<users>
            |  <user username="test1234" role="admin">
            |    <permission interface="com.test.RoleManagement" implementation="com.test.AdminRoleManagement"/>
            |    <permission interface="com.test.UserAdministration" implementation="com.test.UserAdministrationImpl"/>
            |  </user>
            |</users>'''.stripMargin()

def root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

def admins = root.user.findAll { it.@role == "admin" }

admins.each { admin ->
  admin.permission.findAll {
    it.@interface == "com.test.RoleManagement" 
  }.each {
    it.@implementation = "AdminRoleManagement"
  }
}

String output = new StringWriter().with { sw ->
  new XmlNodePrinter( new PrintWriter( sw ) ).print( root )
  sw.toString()
}
println output
```

That prints:

```
<users>
  <user username="test1234" role="admin">
    <permission interface="com.test.RoleManagement" implementation="AdminRoleManagement"/>
    <permission interface="com.test.UserAdministration" implementation="com.test.UserAdministrationImpl"/>
  </user>
</users>
```

Which at first glance seems right?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  I was hoping there was a way to format the data on the other side (during the printing) maybe.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: wow - i'm an idiot.  I tried that but it was after I had already overwrote my file using XmlSlurper/StreamingMarkupBuilder, which did not preserve the order.  This works for me.  Thanks tim, you're awesome - second time today you helped me.

Comment: @jeff glad to help :-)  Good luck, and hope the boss likes it ;-)

Comment: The example XMLParser code isn't working in Groovy 1.8 or 2.2.  The changes aren't reflected in the output - com.test.AdminRoleManagement should be replaced by AdminRoleManagement.